# Structure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that homomorphisms $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are exactly polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, model-theory

If we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$, then the maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ preserving this structure are exactly the *linear maps* $x \mapsto ax$. In contrast, if we think of $\mathbb{R}$ as an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) instead, the maps preserving this structure are exactly the *affine maps* $x \mapsto ax + b$.

**Is it possible to "forget" even more structure, and have a structure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ preserving this structure are *exactly* the polynomials?**

I'll leave it up to you what ring to take coefficients of polynomials from. If anyone could do it for $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{C}$ instead, I'll be equally happy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The structure is that of an [affine variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_variety) or affine algebraic set. In general, as a set, it is the zero-locus in $\mathbb{A}^n(k)=k^n$ of some finite family of polynomials (that generate a prime ideal for a variety). For $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ itself we take the zero polynomial. This is usually considered over $k=\mathbb{C}$, or some other algebraically closed field, not $\mathbb{R}$. However, one can restrict to considering real points in it.  In this case we will take the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1(k)$. Morphisms of affine varieties are functions that are polynomials in each coordinate, in this case, a single coordinate. What they preserve is the coordinate ring, in this case the ring of all polynomials, compositions of polynomials with polynomials are again polynomials. This makes it a type of [ringed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringed_space).

Comment: But to say something is an affine variety doesn't make it into a structure in the sense of model theory.

Comment: @RobArthan Neither does specifying topology, differential structure or a structure sheaf. So much the worse for model theory, its conception of structure is too narrow. They are ["mathematical structures"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) in the sense of Bourbaki.

Comment: I only made the point because the OP used the model-theory tag.

Comment: In defense of structures in the sense of model theory: this conception of structure is "too narrow" for what purpose? For describing every object of interest in mathematics? Of course it is too narrow. But as a framework that includes many fundamental examples of structures from across mathematics, and also allows one to prove many non-trivial theorems, it has been incredibly successful. Bourbaki's definition of "structure" is much broader, to its credit. But I don't think people actually *use* this definition - my understanding is that even Bourbaki rarely used it after writing it down.

Comment: @AlexKruckman It is too narrow for endowing objects with "structure" and then studying maps that "preserve" it, as informally and widely used. This notion of "structure" is more general than operations + relations, and is formally reflected, for example, in category theory with its objects and morphisms.

Answer (score 7):

Conifold's answer is the right one: The structure of $\mathbb{R}$ as the affine line over $\mathbb{R}$ is the canonical one in which the endomorphisms are the polynomial maps in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

I just want to follow up on Rob Arthan's comment, since you use the model theory tag. When we view $\mathbb{R}$ as an affine variety, we are not viewing it as a structure in the sense of model theory. In fact, there is **no** way of equipping $\mathbb{R}$ with constant, function, and relation symbols in such a way that the homomorphisms $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are exactly the polynomials.

Let's suppose that we're viewing $\mathbb{R}$ as an $L$-structure in such a way that every polynomial map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a homomorphism. Suppose $P$ is an $n$-ary relation symbol in the language, and suppose $\mathbb{R}\models P(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ for some *distinct* $a_1,\dots,a_n\in \mathbb{R}$. Now for any *distinct* $b_1,\dots,b_n\in \mathbb{R}$, there is some polynomial $f\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree $n-1$ so that $f(a_i) = b_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$. Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $\mathbb{R}\models P(b_1,\dots,b_n)$. Thus if $P$ holds of *any* $n$-tuple of distinct elements, it holds of *every* $n$-tuple of distinct elements.

A similar argument shows that for each relation symbol in the language, if the relation symbol holds of *some* tuple (possibly with repeats), then it holds of *every* tuple that has the same pattern of repeats. For example, if $\mathbb{R}\models P(a,b,a)$ with $b\neq a$, then $\mathbb{R}\models P(c,d,c)$ for all $c\neq d$. The same argument also shows that there can be no constant symbols in the language, and any $n$-ary function symbol in the language must be interpreted to always return one its $n$ inputs, and which input it returns only depends on the pattern of repeats in the tuple of inputs (apply the argument to the graph relation $g(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}) = x_n$).

Now you can check that in a trivial language like this, *any* function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a homomorphism. In particular, there are many endomorphisms which are not polynomials.